# Activity Dashboard for LocalHost

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping

ESRI recently put out a new tool called the '[Activity Dashboard](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/02/09/activity-dashboard-for-arcgis-now-available/)' that checks for new maps created, map uses, etc. Sadly, this tool only works for those maps created through the ArcGIS online system.

One of the problems I have as the new 'Web Map' guy for my organization is that multiple maps have been created, all of them as (basically) one-offs to fix a specific problem, and no one has a master list of them or the services they are running on. This left me with a very annoying situation. I 'thought' I knew about them all, but I find that I am regularly learning about old maps as they break. The recent address locator that ESRI killed off brought SEVERAL maps to my attention that I wasn't even aware of.

I am wondering if there are any tools that have been developed that track maps and/or services that have been created to give someone in my position a better chance of managing this system.